# Bulk insert task fails, BUT actually succeeds?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, etl

I made a simple bulk task to load data from a 3-4 kb csv (.txt) file. All the data is loaded correctly and yet SSIS shows that its failed. I don't get it. Why ?

The so-called error is -

[Bulk Insert Task] Error: An error occurred with the following error message: "Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 1 (My_ID).".

I am using SSIS 2008 and SQL server 2008 for this one.

Comment: Did you set your setting to continue on failure in the SSIS package ?? are you sure you have got all the rows in you table after this error occurred  ? because it seems like your text file had some column names and you didnt set the FIRSTROW = 2 in your bulk insert statement.

Comment: That makes sense. I had not set FirstRow = 2. It was 1. You can put this as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set your setting to continue on failure in the SSIS package ?? are you sure you have got all the rows in you table after this error occurred ? because it seems like your text file had some column names and you didnt set the `FIRSTROW = 2` in your bulk insert statement.

Comment: Not a problem pal, glad I could help :)

Comment: and in most of the cases its better to stop execution in case of error, if its a scheduled job set yourself to receive an email on failure and stop the execution. Fix the problem and re-execute it, saves you a lot of maintenance work :)